# Clarification on BMI formula

Tags: human-biology

In the BMI formula= (Weight)  X  703) / (Height^2) , what does 703 represent? What is a reliable source that I can cite for this answer?

weight= lbs    height= inches

Comment: I think it has to do with the conversion: normally the formula is used on a metric scale. the units are weight in kg and height in meters. 1 pound = 0.45 kg. 1 inch = 0.0245 meters. 0.45/(0.0245)^2 = 756. So I must say the 703 is kind of odd. But I think it's a conversion factor

Answer (score 5):

It's a conversion factor.

$$ 1~lbs = 0.453592~kg \\
1~in = 0.0254000~m $$

$$ \frac{lbs}{in^2} = \frac{0.453592~kg}{(0.0254~m)^2} = \frac{703.069~kg}{m^2} $$